# can't translate facebook open graph story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

I've created 2 open graph stories for my app on facebook, and they have been approved. Now I'm trying to translate them. I was able to translate one of them, but the other one doesn't show in the localize section. Even, using inline translation, the story shows underlined, but when I rigth click on it, the translation window never shows.
What can I do to translate this story?
Thanks